# Compilation error for discontinuous function definition

Tags: equations, errors

I am trying to render the following discontinuous function definition

[image]

with the LaTeX code:

```
\begin{equation}
 f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0,5x & \text{for x} \in [0, 10] \\
       0,55x + 5 & \text{for x} \in (10, 30] \\
       0,1x + 25 & \text{for x} \in (30, 40] \\
       0,6x + 10 & \text{for x} \in (40, +\infty)
     \end{array}.
   \right
\end{equation}
```

At Texify and other online LaTeX equation editors, this code renders fine (as you can see), but if I use this code in my document at the compilation time I get errors:

```
Missing delimeter (. insterted)
Missing $ inserted
Display math should end with $$
Bad math environment delimenter. \end{equation}
You can't use '\egno' in vertical mode \end{equation}
Missing $ inserted \end{equation}
Display math should end with $$ \end{equation}
```

I have used LaTeX for rendering equations for two weeks so sorry for my poor knowledge (probably it will be something obvious for most of you).

Comment: You should put the `x` outside `\text{...}`, as it's math, not text. Also, you may consider using `\text{for $x \in (10, 30]$}` which makes copy/pasting/reusing from or in other parts of the document easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write `\right.` instead of just `\right`, the dot is required for a phantom delimiter.

[image: output]

However, you could use the `cases` environment of `amsmath` instead of this array.

```
\begin{equation}
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
       0,5x & \text{for x} \in [0, 10] \\
       0,55x + 5 & \text{for x} \in (10, 30] \\
       0,1x + 25 & \text{for x} \in (30, 40] \\
       0,6x + 10 & \text{for x} \in (40, +\infty)
     \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

[image: cases example]

You don't need to write `\left\{` and `\right.`. Note, the text is left aligned here, which could be more desirable.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. What i noticed, is that the left bracket (in both cases) looks like it was crossed by some horizontal (white) lines. If I change the zoom, there is more or less of these lines and they appear in different places - so I assume that's a reader application issue (or my monitor:)) and these lines will not be visible in the output document?

Comment: @Piotrek: yes it's a displaying issue (not of your monitor) of the composed symbol. It should be fine in print because of the higher resolution.

Comment: @Stefan: `x` should be *outside* `\text{...}`. In fact, it's often better to write `\text{for $x \in (10, 30]$}` as it makes copy/pasting/reusing from or in other parts of the document easier. Also, note that unless you use `\begin{array}{@{}lr}`, the solution with `{array}` will have too much space between the brace and the equations.

Comment: @Philippe: that's correct, as can bee seen in the output images, good addition. It would be good to address your comment to Piotrek, as it may help him.